# Capistranoでデプロイする際にlibmysqlclientのロードエラーが発生する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, デプロイ, capistrano

AWSでRailsをデプロイする際に、表題のエラーが出ており、ネット上の記事などを参照したのですが、解決できませんでした。

尚、デプロイはCapistrano3をしようしております。

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173
```

### 今回のエラー内容

> LoadError: /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18: version `libmysqlclient_16' not found (required by /var/project_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.20/mysql2/mysql2.so) - /var/project_name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.20/mysql2/mysql2.so

### 参考にした記事

http://qiita.com/pollseed/items/b7d187dbbd64b29820d4#%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C3-1libmysqlclient%E5%91%A8%E3%82%8A

この記事の

```
$ ldd /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18
```

のところまでは同じように設定し、結果も同じものが返っております。

※mysqlは記事と同じバージョンに合わせております。

ただ、記事中にある

```
ldd .rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.18/mysql2/mysql2.so
ldd .rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/ext/mysql2/mysql2.so
ldd .rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
```

の`.rbenv`というのがそもそもなかったため、

```
$ pwd
/var/project_name/releases/20160605065652
```

の配下で実行した際に、エラーがでるため、この部分はできておりません。
(No such file or directory)

ちなみにrbenv自体はインストールできているはずです。

```
$ which rbenv
/usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv
```

rbenvの問題なのか、mysql側の問題なのか、それ以外なのか、
原因がわからなくなってしまいました。

調べていると、socketが原因だったという記事や、my.cnfの設定ミスが原因だったとか色々あり、混乱してます。

socketとmy.cnfについては再三確認をしております。

socketはrailsのdatabase.ymlとあわせて、`/tmp/mysql.sock`に統一しております。

```
[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1
skip-grant-tables


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[client]
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

尚、サーバー上で、mysqlコマンドをたたくと、きちんとmysqlが起動します。

どなたかアドバイス頂けますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/37009　マルチポスト

Answer (score 1):

mysql2.so をコンパイルした環境の libmysqlclient と実行環境の libmysqlclient が異なるためだと思います。

実行環境で mysql2.so をコンパイルし直してみるのが良いと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
まだ、プログラミング経験自体が浅く、理解が追いついていないのですが、実行環境というのは、ローカル環境ではなく、サーバー側ということですよね？また、mysql2.so をコンパイルし直しなおすとのことでしたが、「関連ワード」で検索するとこういう記事が多く出ていたので、そこら辺の対応はしましたが、解決できませんでした。
http://y-ken.hatenablog.com/entry/inside-of-libmysqlclient-with-mysql-shared-compat

コンパイルとは違うのかなとおもったのですが、コンパイルとはどこのコンパイルを指されているのでしょうか？

Comment: こういうのも試しました
http://www.sssg.org/blogs/naoya/archives/2536

http://qiita.com/caramelbit/items/938290c8fce954c58abf

Comment: 実行環境と書いたのはサーバー側のことです。
mysql2.so は C のソースをコンパイルしたものです。誰かがどこかでコンパイルしているはずです。
そのコンパイルした環境とサーバーの環境が異なっているためにエラーが出ているのではないかと思ったのでした。